# FloMAT library export

Tags: svg, medial-axis

I have discovered the floMAT library for determining the medial axis transform of 2D shapes. It looks realy great but I wonder if there is any simple way to export the MAT data in a text file. I only succeeded to get outputs as images. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What format did you have in mind for the text file? SVG?